what package to install to get #define of TIOCGPTN in MSYS2
title says it all, I hope... I don't know what header to look in and I don't know which package would give me that header... I don't know where to get my hands on the source code to do a full text search

I'm wondering if you can try this (found on Linux) : #define TIOCGPTN    _IOR('T', 0x30, unsigned int)

quite possibly yes but I REALLY hope I don't have to...

but perhaps this is indeed the correct value, since I do have #define TIOCSWINSZ (('T' << 8) | 2) and #define TIOCSPGRP  (('T' << 8) | 0x10) ... I further have #define TIOCSCTTY       0x540E and #define TIOCSBRK        0x5427 and 'T'<<8 just happens to equal 0x54

Try that first. If it works, you can still continue to look for a better solution.

fair enough... could you tell me where you found this?  I need TIOCSPTLCK even more than I need TIOCGPTN

On Fedora/Linux : /usr/include/asm-generic/ioctls.h:#define TIOCGPTN   _IOR('T', 0x30, unsigned int) /* Get Pty Number (of pty-mux device) */, but I think TIOCGPTN might not be supported on Cygwin.

that would make me sad... I don't have asm-generic or ioctls.h ... I suspect it supports it but the header is in some obscure package where I can't find it

it's not working for me but I think the issue is that I'm using it wrong... I tried it on a Linux system and it failed there too... most docs for ioctl assume you're using C and I'm trying to call it from Perl, which I've never done before

see discussion here for the REAL numbers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78592493/third-param-for-ioctl-in-perl
