third param for ioctl in Perl
Background: I'm trying to create a pseudo-terminal using only the tools that come with "Git for windows" so please don't tell me "just install tool XYZ" if XYZ requires extra native binaries.  (Actually, feel free to mention XYZ since it may be useful to others, but it likely won't help me.)
With that background out of the way, the rest of this question actually assumes we're on Linux, because Linux has strace and I can't live without strace.
So, consider this code snippet...
open PTMX, '/dev/ptmx';
my $out = "1234";  # is this right??
my $ret = ioctl PTMX, 0x5430, $out;  # hardcode number for now
if (!$ret) {
   say "errno is $!"
} else {
   say "out is $out; ret is $ret"
}

When I run this using strace -e ioctl /usr/bin/perl t.pl I see that

It's passing file descriptor 3, as expected.  Good!
The ioctl number got resolved to TIOCGPTN, which is what I hoped for.  Great!
But the call fails with EINVAL (Invalid argument)

Thus I conclude that the trouble is with the third parameter.  At the C level, I want to pass a pointer to an integer but I can't figure out from the docs at https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ioctl how to do so.

Have you tried my $out = pack i => 1234; instead?

Does Windows even support ptys?

And see the perlport note about ioctl

@ Shawn... Windows does not, but Cygwin does.  Git does really run natively on Windows... the "git for windows" distribution is actually a stripped down Cygwin / msys2 installation ... as far as git knows, it's running on a POSIX system, and this also applies to the Perl that gets shipped with git.  A native windows build of perl does NOT support ptys, but this one does, because as far as it knows, it's not running on an OS called "windows" but rather on one called "cygwin"/

@ choroba ... I have not tried that ... it does not seem clear to me why that might help... the value 1234 is arbitrary ... my goal is to pass a pointer to an integer which the kernel will overwrite with the value I want... thus I want to ensure that the kernel has at least 4 bytes of space to write the answer in, since that's how big an int is... pack can give me a string of length 4, but I can create a string of length four without its help, right?

@ikegami I saw your answer briefly but now it's gone... presumably because it had the same issue?

@Mark VY, I have replaced/updated my answer.

The following program works on Linux (tested in a WSL2 VM):
use v5.36;

use constant TIOCGPTN => 0x80045430;

my $ptmx_qfn = "/dev/ptmx";

open( my $ptmx_fh, "<", $ptmx_qfn )
   or die( "Can't open `$ptmx_qfn`: $!\n" );

my $buf = pack( "I", 0 );  # Allocate space

ioctl( $ptmx_fh, TIOCGPTN, $buf )
   or die( "Can't get pty number: $!" );

my $num = unpack( "I", $buf );

say $num;  # 1

Note the correct value of TIOCGPTN.
But it doesn't work on Cygwin, and I presume it doesn't work in MSYS (the similar unix emulation environment used by "Git for Windows") either. I conclude that TIOCGPTN isn't supported by them.


I conclude that the trouble is with the third parameter.

Your third parameter is surely correct despite the assumptions about the size of unsigned int.

Going forward
Instead of installing "Git for Windows" and having to recreate the tools you need, you could install Cygwin. It provides a similar unix emulation environment as the one provided by MSYS used by "Git for Windows". The advantage of using Cygwin over MSYS is that it comes with a (well-stocked) package manager which allows you to easily add more tools, including git.

A side note on constructing TIOCGPTN
use constant {
   _IOC_NRBITS   =>  8,
   _IOC_TYPEBITS =>  8,
   _IOC_SIZEBITS => 14,  # Varies by system.
   _IOC_DIRBITS  =>  2,  # Varies by system.

   _IOC_NONE  => 0,  # Varies by system.
   _IOC_READ  => 1,  # Varies by system.
   _IOC_WRITE => 2,  # Varies by system.
};

sub _IOC {
   return
      ( $_[2] << ( 0                                               )
      | $_[1] << ( 0 + _IOC_NRBITS                                 )
      | $_[3] << ( 0 + _IOC_NRBITS + _IOC_TYPEBITS                 )
      | $_[0] << ( 0 + _IOC_NRBITS + _IOC_TYPEBITS + _IOC_SIZEBITS )
      );
}

use constant _UINT_SZ => length( pack( "I", 0 ) );

use constant TIOCGPTN => _IOC( _IOC_WRITE, ord( "T" ), 0x30, _UINT_SZ );


Took me an age to find this. h2ph / sys/ioctls.ph have a nasty bug where they compute the wrong value for ioctls that are defined with the _IOC macro, because that macro uses sizeof(the type), and h2ph resolves sizeof(unsigned long) to $sizeof{'unsigned long'}, and then just says "BUGS: doesn't construct the %sizeof array for you". Which means it thinks that TIOCGPTN is 0x80005430 instead of 0x80045430. Argh.

re: install better stuff: this is not for me... I want me make a cute little tool and distribute it to a small group at work... telling people to install hundreds of megs of stuff to run a small script is somehow not very attractive, especially when it comes to figuring out whether corporate policy even allows installing Cygwin

Then why are you writing a program for a different OS than the one your users use?!

I'm not :) ... I'm using Git for Windows ... I switched to a Linux system when nothing seemed to work and it seemed like a promising way to reduce the number of variables in play

"Git for Windows" is MSYS, a unix emulation environment. So my (rhetorical) question stands. Seems to me that it would make more sense to write a new tool for distribution in the native OS instead of involving another OS.

But the whole point is make use of what people already have installed... the ONLY reason I can count on the fact that perl is already installed is because I know that git is already installed.  So yes, I'm stuck with msys, or msys2, or whatever it's called...  all sorts of options open up if you drop the constraint that they shouldn't have to install extra stuff... or at least, that the extra stuff shouldn't be too many orders of magnitude "heavier" than my script.  My script will likely be between 1kb and 10kb of source code by the time I'm done with it... Cygwin is quite a bit more than that

re: wrong ioctl... that's so weird!  then why did strace seem to understand what I want?  how did you manage to figure that out so fast?

re: algorithm to rederive constant: I wish I could upvote this twice.  But something seems off... DIRBITS seems unused entirely, and it computes a different constant than you got.  For instance, _IOC_WRITE=2 in the low-order bits means the last hex digit should be 2, not 0, right?

Re "Cygwin is quite a bit more than that", Writing for Cygwin isn't writing for the native OS either.  /// Re "I know that [MSYS] is already installed", So then why not install the MSYS-compiled tools you need instead of rewriting them? /// Re "DIRBITS seems unused entirely", Correct. We shift by the combined size of the previous fields. /// Re "_IOC_WRITE=2 in the low-order bits means the last hex digit should be 2", No. We're not multiplying by a power of 16 aka shifting by a power of 4. _IOC_WRITE  = 0b10, and TIOCGPTN = 0b[10][00 0000 0000 0100] [0101 0100] [0011 0000]

re: Cygwin is not native either: good point; not sure what I was thinking when I wrote that... re: why not install stuff: I specifically mentioned this in the original question: "don't tell me to install XYZ if XYZ requires native binaries" because I don't want to ship extra dependencies... the whole thing should be one or worst case two small text files... if I was willing to install extra binaries I'd be approaching the whole problem differently

Re "I specifically mentioned this in the original question", No you didn't. I said MSYS tools, not native ones. /// Re "If I was willing to install extra binaries I'd be approaching the whole problem differently", Aren't you following? That's the point I'm making. You're using a foreign OS and re-inventing wheels. BAD!

sorry... I should have been more specific... those are still "native enough" for me to not want them... (from "inside" the program everything looks like POSIX but to windows itself it's a normal win32 app) ... I should not even have said "native" at all... what I don't want is stuff that is "heavy" which could mean disk space or needing a fancy installer or needing to navigate corporate policies

Cause defying the policies is way better.

um, am I in fact defying any policies this way?  I thought not

re: IOC_WRITE ... I can't quite follow what you're saying here... that's being shifted by 0, so it should still be in the least significant nibble (nyblle?), right?

Of course! You're relying on the fact that whatever prevents you from adding the binary won't catch your Perl rewrite of the program.

Re "that's being shifted by 0", not supposed to. I got the args wrong. Fixed.

re: won't get caught... I'm software developer... there's no rule that says I'm not allowed to write code; that is what they're paying me to do.  There ARE rules about downloading random executables from the internet.  You could say that makes no sense, but it actually does make a certain sick kind of sense... it's tantamount to saying "we trust the code you write yourself, but we don't trust you to properly audit code you get from elsewhere"

re: "I conclude that TIOCGPTN isn't supported by them" ... that would be a fair conclusion except that things like tmux and screen exist in the msys2 package manager and work... so there's got to be some subtlety we're missing.

No. You're assuming they use TIOCGPTN.

That's a good point... one might be able to work around the lack of that particular ioctl ... but I can't think of any way to work around the lack of TIOCSPTLCK (0x31 instead of 0x30) which is used by unlockpt() ... so there's still something weird going on here....

strace the program you are trying to replicate

Probably I should try to get my own copy of Linux instead of experimenting on a shared server then... I'll see what I can do

No, not in Linux. You're trying to figure how to make it work in MSYS. You need to strace the MSYS program.

strace on msys does not show the POSIX version of the sys calls, but instead shows what's going on at the win32 level, which is not enlightening (at least for me)

Looks like you were right... these ioctls are NOT supported... the high-level functions explicitly specified by POSIX (such as ptsname) are supported, but contrary to my expectations, those functions are not implemented in terms of these ioctls... it seems to be implemented in terms of a class called cygheap_fdget
